# Combine the same column from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql-server, join

I am joining two tables `HR` and `UserDefined` based on the `Employee_ID`:

**HR Table**

```
First Name  Last Name   Employee_ID
----------  ---------   -----------
Joe         Smith       456654
```

**User Defined Table**

```
Area    ud_1_text   ud_2_text   Employee_ID
----    ---------   ----------  -----------
1       ABCD1234    31/08/2018  456654
2       69090       23/05/2022  456654
```

Now I know that if `Area` equals `1` then it is a "Drivers Licence" and if `Area` equals `2` that it is a "First Aid Certification".

I would like to be able to return the following in one line per `Employee_ID`:

```
Employee_ID First Name  Last name   D/L Number  Expiry      First Aid Expiry
----------- ----------  ---------   ----------  ----------  --------- ----------
456654      Joe         Smith       ABCD1234    31/08/2018  69090     23/05/2022
```

Any ideas on how to do this?
Microsoft SQL Server query please.

Comment: how your are identifying the D/L number from the two row?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have both an Area 1 and Area 2 value for each record? If not, what do you expect to see as output?

Comment: Good point - it turns out there wasn't a guaranteed entry for Area 1 and Area 2 so the solution I used below was missing rows. However - this was due to bad data  - so once I fixed that up and ensured there was data in these two areas the simple 2 join solution worked and got me what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join to `User Defined Table` twice, once with `Area = 1` and once with `Area = 2`.

```
from [HR Table] as HT
  inner join [User Defined Table] as UT1
    on HT.Employee_ID = UT1.Employee_ID and
       UT1.Area = 1
  inner join [User Defined Table] as UT2
    on HT.Employee_ID = UT2.Employee_ID and
       UT2.Area = 2
```

Get the `D/L Number` with `Expiry` from `UT1` and `First Aid` with `Expiry` from `UT2`

Comment: This worked great - nice and simple and gave me what I needed. Thanks to everyone for all the quick feedback. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Took the cte code from @Aduguid, another alternative is

```
;WITH
hr_table
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Joe', 'Smith', 456654)
    ) tbl ([First Name], [Last Name], [Employee_ID]) 
)
, 
user_defined_table
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'ABCD1234', '31-Aug-2018', 456654)
    , ( 2, '69090', '23-May-2022', 456654)
    ) tbl ([Area], [ud_1_text], [ud_2_text], [Employee_ID]) 
)

SELECT h.Employee_ID,h.[First Name],h.[Last Name],
MAX(CASE WHEN u.Area=1 THEN u.ud_1_text ELSE '' END) AS [D/L Number],
MAX(CASE WHEN u.Area=1 THEN u.ud_2_text ELSE '' END) AS [expiry],
MAX(CASE WHEN u.Area=2 THEN u.ud_1_text ELSE '' END) AS [First Aid],
MAX(CASE WHEN u.Area=2 THEN u.ud_2_text ELSE '' END) AS [expiry]
 FROM hr_table h
INNER JOIN user_defined_table u
ON h.Employee_ID=u.Employee_ID
GROUP BY h.Employee_ID,h.[First Name],h.[Last Name]
```

---

Comment: Nice work with the SQL

Comment: @aduguid, thanks. I always use this type of static pivot for most cases for a year wise monthly report, another one using row number function to find last three records and pivot them to get single row likewise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve this.

```
WITH
hr_table
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Joe', 'Smith', 456654)
    ) tbl ([First Name], [Last Name], [Employee_ID]) 
)
, 
user_defined_label
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'Drivers Licence')
    , ( 2, 'First Aid Cerification')
    ) tbl ([Area], [Description]) 
)
,
user_defined_table
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'ABCD1234', '31-Aug-2018', 456654)
    , ( 2, '69090', '23-May-2022', 456654)
    ) tbl ([Area], [ud_1_text], [ud_2_text], [Employee_ID]) 
)
, 
user_defined_list
AS
(
    SELECT
          hr.[First Name]
        , hr.[Last Name]
        , hr.[Employee_ID]
        , val.[Area]
        , lbl.[Description]
        , val.[ud_1_text]
        , val.[ud_2_text]
    FROM 
        hr_table AS hr
        INNER JOIN user_defined_table AS val ON hr.[Employee_ID] = val.[Employee_ID]
        INNER JOIN user_defined_label AS lbl ON val.[Area] = lbl.[Area]
)
SELECT 
      dsc.[First Name]
    , dsc.[Last Name]
    , dsc.[Employee_ID]
    , dsc.[Drivers Licence] 
    , [Drivers Licence Expiry] = dte.[Drivers Licence] 
    , dsc.[First Aid Cerification]
    , [First Aid Cerification Expiry] = dte.[First Aid Cerification]
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
          ud.[First Name]
        , ud.[Last Name]
        , ud.[Employee_ID]
        , ud.[Description]
        , ud.[ud_1_text]
    FROM 
        user_defined_list AS ud
    ) AS ud
        PIVOT
            (
            MAX(ud.[ud_1_text]) 
            FOR ud.[Description] IN ([Drivers Licence], [First Aid Cerification])
            ) AS dsc
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
              ds.[Employee_ID]
            , ds.[Drivers Licence] 
            , ds.[First Aid Cerification]
        FROM 
            (
            SELECT
                  ud.[First Name]
                , ud.[Last Name]
                , ud.[Employee_ID]
                , ud.[Description]
                , ud.[ud_2_text]
            FROM 
                user_defined_list AS ud
            ) AS ud
        PIVOT
            (MAX(ud.[ud_2_text]) 
            FOR ud.[Description] IN ([Drivers Licence], [First Aid Cerification])) AS ds 
    ) AS dte ON dte.[Employee_ID] = dsc.[Employee_ID]
```

[image: screenshot]